# Creating a string by iterating thru list,, dict and constants

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, dictionary

Beginner issue here. I am sure there is a more pythonic way of doing this. basically I need to create a string using the contents of a list and a dict, plus I need to insert constants. I am trying to produce a end product for a function call via Eval. My current code works but it smells of 1980s BASIC (which ages me). I've looked at .join, zip and itter package  but with no luck.

The list (argumentlist) contains argument names (such as open, close, length) and the dict (self.indicator_paremeters) contains all potential argument names along with their default value. So for example within the dict there is a key 'length' and its default value.  In addition I need to concatenate '+' and commas, to create the end string.

Here is code sample to date.

```
    def loop_thru_arguement_list_to_create_end_string(self, argument, resultant_argument_string):
        if resultant_argument_string == "":
            resultant_argument_string = argument + ' = ' + str(self.indicator_paremeters.get(
            argument))
        else:
            resultant_argument_string = resultant_argument_string + ", " + argument + ' = ' + str(
            self.indicator_paremeters.get(
                argument))
        return resultant_argument_string
```

This function is called from the loop here (need to rename that function):

```
    def extract_argument_list_from_function(self, fullarguments) -> str:
        resultant_argument_string = ""
        argumentlist = fullarguments[0]
        for argument in argumentlist:
            resultant_argument_string = self.loop_thru_arguement_list_to_create_end_string(argument,
                                                                                       resultant_argument_string)
        return resultant_argument_string
```

fullarguments = is a dict from a inspect.getfullargspec call. I only want the args, hence the [0].

All methods above  are in a wider class.

self.indicator_paremeters is the dict holding all potential arguments.

The code above works fine but just doesn't feel right. **Its the IF statement in particular which doesn't feel pythonic.**

Comment: You can most certainly narrow the scope of your question down to a simple set of inputs and a desired output. The extraneous functions you have defined seem to detract from the essence of your question here.

Comment: One thing that could help is string interpolation. Something like `'{key}={val}'.format(key='foo', val='bar')`.

Comment: or simply `res = f'{key}={val}'`

Comment: if `fullarguments` is a dict, then how come you can use `fullarguments[0]` ? It looks like a list/tuple to me ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you just need this:

```
def extract_argument_list_from_function(self, fullarguments: List) -> str:
    res = ''
    for arg in fullarguments[0]:
        param = self.indicator_paremeters.get(arg)
        res = f'{res}, {arg} = {param}' if res else f'{arg} = {param}'
    
    return res
```

you can delete the `loop_thru_arguement_list_to_create_end_string` method

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a look. I haven't fully grasped the use of the f formatting tool as yet. It is clearly more powerful than I can guess at at mo. I used fullargument[0] to get to the first list within the dict. I understood that the function produces three lists within the dict from the call fullarguements = inspect.getfullargspec(eval(function_name))